# ¿Si quiero que una clase que hereda de una clase abstracta tenga un atributo static, tengo que declararlo en la clase padre?

Tags: c++, poo, objeto, herencia, clase-abstracta

Como puedo declarar un método static que sea distinto para cada clase hija. Por ejemplo, si tengo una clase padre Edificio(), que es es abstracta, y quiero crear la clase Escuela() y Aserradero(), que heredan de Edificio(), y que cada una tenga su propio contador static para saber cuantas veces se instanciaron cada una, ¿se puede hacer?, ¿como y donde debería declararlo?, porque llevo rato buscando e intentando pero siempre me tira el "undefined reference".

Esta es la idea que estuve probando (el método saludar es simplemente para hacerla abstracta, irían otros métodos que tienen sentido):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    class Edificio {
        protected:
            int coordenada_x;
            int coordenada_y;
    
        public:
            Edificio() {}
    
            virtual void saludar() = 0;
    };
    
    class Aserradero : public Edificio {
        private:
            static int construidos;
        public:
            Aserradero() {}
    
            Aserradero(int coordenada_x, int coordenada_y) {
                this -> coordenada_x = coordenada_x;
                this -> coordenada_y = coordenada_y;
                construidos++;
            }
    
            void saludar() {
                cout << "hola" << endl;
            }
    };
    
    class Escuela : public Edificio {
        private:
            static int construidos;
        public:
            Escuela() {}
    
            Escuela(int coordenada_x, int coordenada_y) {
                this -> coordenada_x = coordenada_x;
                this -> coordenada_y = coordenada_y;
                construidos++;
            }
    
            void saludar() {
                cout << "hola" << endl;
            }
    };
    
    int main() {
        Aserradero* aserradero = new Aserradero(5, 6);
        Escuela* escuela1 = new Escuela(7, 6);
        Escuela* escuela2 = new Escuela(6, 6);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta inicializar los miembros estáticos:

```
    ... resto de código
    int Aserradero::construidos = 0;
    int Escuela::construidos = 0;
     
    int main() {
        Aserradero* aserradero = new Aserradero(5, 6);
        Escuela* escuela1 = new Escuela(7, 6);
        Escuela* escuela2 = new Escuela(6, 6);
        return 0;
    }
```